# inserting a date into Oracle Database using Python

Tags: python, oracle

I want to add a date to my database Oracle but I have problems.

This is my code:

```
    idcompte= request.GET.get('idcompte','')
    nomcompte = request.GET.get('nomcompte','')
    datecreation = request.GET.get ('datecreation','')          

    conn=cx.connect('x/x@y')
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    add_compte = ("INSERT INTO COMPTE "
    "VALUES (%(idcompte)s, %(nomcompte)s, %(datecreation)s)")
    data_compte = {
  'idcompte': idcompte,
  'nomcompte': nomcompte,
  'datecreation': date(datecreation),
  }

    cursor.execute(add_compte, data_compte)
```

But the error that I have is : "an integer is required"

Comment: It seems like this is a Python error, and not an Oracle error. Which line of code generates this error?

Comment: thanks for you response : this line code generates this error :                                          'datecreation': date(datecreation),

Comment: In that case - I don't see how is the issue related to Oracle in any way. Having said that - what is the value of datecreation?

Comment: i know that the value of function date is (year-month-day) but the probleme is i don't knopw why this function doesn't accept datecreation or datecreation is the value recuperated from a formulaire and it has this forma of the function date .are you have another solution ?

Comment: Since the function claims it expects an integer, I highly doubt it's expecting a year-month-day format. Can you provide any kind of reference to this function?

Comment: Without more information, I fear I cannot. Good luck.